# error: assigning to 'char' from incompatible type 'const char *'

Tags: c++

I am getting this error when trying to compile my code.

> error: assigning to 'char' from incompatible type 'const char *'

The function in reference is

```
void stringCopy(char *destination, const char *source) {
   while(source != '\0') {
       destination = source;
       destination++, source++;
    }
}
```

I do know there is a built in `strcpy()` in C++ but for what I am doing, it was requested that we make one from scratch.

Comment: Maybe you want `*destination = *source;` instead of `destination = source;`

Comment: Probably a good idea to null terminate the destination string too.

Comment: You have to look up the dereference operator.

Comment: @dreadedslug when an answer provides a solution to your problem but you (after fixing) come across a different problem, you should create a *new question* instead of editing.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x There are already several answered questions about pointer problems, and the error produced might still be the same as before.

Comment: @Cppplus1 the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48603227/revisions) had no mention of bus error 10, and while a potential duplicate, it was answered sufficiently below. But since it has been edited (beyond typos or more information to the original question) the answer is no longer a match.

Comment: The cause of the bus error could also be in the caller (e.g. passing a bad pointer as one or both arguments to the function).   As written (at least, until the question is edited again) the function assumes `source` points to the first element of a zero-terminated array, and that `destination` points to a buffer long enough to hold the contents of `source` including the terminator.   If either assumption is not true, that may explain the error.

Comment: I've rolled back your original question so it matches the answer given. If you now have a different problem, ask a different question. Keep in mind that this time you will need to provide a complete example, as the code in the edit where you morphed your question to a new one works fine for me: https://ideone.com/UIIeUJ My crystal ball says the error is in the code we cannot see.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `source` is a *pointer* to a character.

The identifier `'\0'` is a *character*.

In the `while` expression, you are comparing a pointer to a character.

You can get the character by *dereferencing* the pointer:

```
while (*source != '\0')
```

In the copy statement, you are copying pointers, not characters.

Review your favorite C++ reference about pointers.

Comment: @DreadedSlug _"In the copy statement, you are copying pointers, not characters."_. The `while` statement contains another error. It will loop forever.

Comment: Bus Error -- possible cause is you are dereferencing a pointer that no long points to a valid location, or dereferencing a null pointer.